# In the iPhone's messages list, where does the date come from?

Tags: messages, sqlite

This is maybe a weird question.  In the iPhone's "Messages" app, the first view is a list of all the chats, sorted by the most recent messages in each chat. To the right of each chat entry is a date (circled in my screenshot) which is the essence of my question. This date seems to be the date of the *last* message received in the chat, even when that message has been subsequently deleted from the chat.

Ultimately I was playing around in the sqlite database to see how the messages were represented in there and I can't figure this out.  The chat list seems to be sorted by the most recent *current* messages in each chat, but that timestamp shown can be the timestamp of a deleted message, which seems weird.

So, why does the messages app show a timestamp for a message that doesn't exist anymore, and where in the sqlite message database does that timestamp live?

[image]

Comment: Interesting forensic question. Which specific database file / access method are you using?

Comment: This file is the sqlite database: 3d0d7e5fb2ce288813306e4d4636395e047a3d28, and the messages themselves ("message" table) have a "date" field that's consistent with the timestamp shown in the message detail view on iPhone. The "chat" table has a "last_read_message_timestamp" which seemed like a good candidate but doesn't seem to match up for me, unless I'm doing something wrong. Just browsing the database with "DB Browser for SQLite" for now.